# How to load Fop configuration file to FopFactory

Tags: java, configuration, ejb, uri, apache-fop

I'm generating PDF file from xml and xsl-fo using Fop-2.1 and spent a lot of time to configure fop configuration file(I'm using cyrillic fonts), in according with https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.1/configuration.html

tested it within command-line, it works fine:

> fop -c conf.xml -xml xml -xsl xsl -pdf pdf

Next i need to do same in java web application. Application is multi-module Maven project.

I got stuck when tried to get FopFactory instance with my configuration file located in resources folder of service module, here is a project tree

> service-module
>
> > src/main/resources
> >
> > > conf/config.xml
>
> web-module

How to create instance of FopFactory with my configuration file?

First i did this:

```
 FopFactory fopFactory = fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(
            new File("/full/path/../resources/conf/config.xml"));
```

in this a project we using EJB container, and of course

> An enterprise bean must not use the java.io package to attempt to access files and directories in the file system.

then I'm trying this one

```
    DefaultConfigurationBuilder cfgBuilder = new DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
    Configuration cfg = null;
    try {
        cfg = cfgBuilder.build(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf/config.xml"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FopFactoryBuilder factoryBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(URI.create("/")).setConfiguration(cfg);
    FopFactory fopFactory = factoryBuilder.build();
```

PDF generating app located in service module. What should i need to set in baseURI?

```
fopFactoryBuilder = new FopFactoryBuilder(baseURI).setConfiguration(cfg);
```

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this correctly?

Comment: had to use previous versions of fop 1.**

Answer (score 4):

I bumped into a similar problem and created a working demo which

- uses fop 2.2.
- loads everything from classpath (even a ttf font to embed into the pdf)

Here it is:

https://github.com/riskop/fop_test

See also this:

[Set FopFactoryBuilder baseURI to jar classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661997/set-fopfactorybuilder-baseuri-to-jar-classpath)