# Apache FOP: Image relative Path in Eclipse Maven Project?

Tags: xml, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

This My first PDF using Xml apache Graphics.

I am using SpringBoot application (Eclipse IDE) and i'm trying to generate some PDF files using Apache FOP 2.1.

My Xsl file (myTemplate.xsl) is under `src/main/resources/xsl` folder 
. The images in my projects are under `src/main/resources/images` folder`

I was able to generate my PDF file using instructions on Apache Fop site when I run my application on localhost (Tomcat Localhost). But I when I deploy the application on Serevr my PDF is generated without images.

In my xsl file, Images are referenced like this.

```
  <fo:external-graphic content-type="image/jpg" src="url('src/main/resources/images/Image1.jpg')" />
```

Is the way I used to reference the image in my xsl Correct ? I did some search on the internet and I found that There is a FOP file configutaion to configurate relative Paths. But I can't find an example to resolve my problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43215974/6440301