# How to add image present in xsl file into the pdf file after upgrading apache FOP from 1.1 to 2.8?

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

The error I get is:

> Image not found.URI:xslfile/ABC.jpg

I wanted to upgrade Apache FOP from 1.1 to 2.8 due to vulnerability issue, but after the upgrade the image is not getting loaded in the pdf file.
I want to insert an Imange in the top left corner of the pdf file. My image is inside src/main/resources/xslfile/ABC.jpg but FOP is giving `Image not found error` even though the path is correct.
The PDF file is getting downloaded with other texts and tables without the image.
Before upgrading i was using Apache FOP 1.1 and everything was working fine.

I have upgraded Apache FOP from 1.1 -> 2.8 and I have an existing PDF created out of XSL-FO and XML,
I have added all these to my code as given in the official Apache FOP [upgrading page](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/2.8/upgrading.html)
I have also created the ClassPathResolver which looks like this

```
package pack;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.fop.apps.io.ResourceResolverFactory;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.io.Resource;
import org.apache.xmlgraphics.io.ResourceResolver;

/**
 * ResourceResolver which loads resources with "classpath:" prefix from the classpath 
 * 
 * Based on this:
 * 
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661997/set-fopfactorybuilder-baseuri-to-jar-classpath
 * 
 */
public class ClasspathResolverURIAdapter implements ResourceResolver {

    private final ResourceResolver wrapped;

    public ClasspathResolverURIAdapter() {
      this.wrapped = ResourceResolverFactory.createDefaultResourceResolver();
    }
    
    @Override
    public Resource getResource(URI uri) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("getresource called, uri is: " + uri + ", path is: " + uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("classpath")) {
            InputStream is = Start.class.getResourceAsStream(uri.getSchemeSpecificPart());
            System.out.println("is: " + is);
            return new Resource(is);
        }
        else {
            return wrapped.getResource(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public OutputStream getOutputStream(URI uri) throws IOException {
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("classpath")) {
            throw new RuntimeException("This is a read only ResourceResolver. You can not use it's outputstream");
        }
        else {
            return wrapped.getOutputStream(uri);
        }
    }

}
```

In my XSL file i have added the image inside <fo:block> as

```
<fo:external-graphic src="xslfile/ABC.jpg"width="40mm" height="10mm" content-width="scale-to-fit"content-height="scale-to-fit" scaling="non-uniform" />
```

But when i deploy the code in server it's creating the pdf but it's not loading the image I added.
I have also tried loading images with PDFBox similar to the zip file provided in this link [fop-pdf-images-2.8-bin.tar.gz](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/fop-pdf-images.html)
Please suggest any solutions if any of you have upgraded apache fop 2.8 with images.